# Setting Multiple Environment Variables In File Through package.json Script

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, package.json

I have a file `ENVVARS` that consists of setting many environment variables e.g.

```
export ENV_VAR1 = 'mongodb://url'
export ENV_VAR2 = 'dbname'
```

I need to set these environment variables before I run my script. I'm trying to do something like so:

`"test": . ENVVARS && npm run test-s`

I have read about the use of `cross-env` for setting environment variables inline, but haven't stumbled upon a solution for what I am trying to do, which is setting multiple environment variables through an external file.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv although they try and push you away from multiple environment files.

Answer (score 0):

Like @VtoCorleno suggested you can use [doenv](http://npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package, which let you set as many `ENV VARIABLES` in `.env` file, you can access them in your program like: `process.env.XYZ`,

Which in your case can be:
`process.env.ENV_VAR1`
`process.env.ENV_VAR2`